# splitting array based on a value in array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I would like to split an array based on its value. Say for example my array is like this

```
 Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [amount] => 800
        [detail] => bus fare
        [student_id] => 16
        [class_id] => 1
        [bill_id] => 5a6c176b0b27a
        [total] => 1800
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [amount] => 1000
        [detail] => tast
        [student_id] => 16
        [class_id] => 1
        [bill_id] => 5a6c176b0b27a
        [total] => 1800
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [amount] => 5000
        [detail] => tution
        [student_id] => 16
        [class_id] => 1
        [bill_id] => 5a6d3a1d67feb
        [total] => 5150
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [amount] => 150
        [detail] => busfare
        [student_id] => 16
        [class_id] => 1
        [bill_id] => 5a6d3a1d67feb
        [total] => 5150
    )
```

)
I would like to split the array in bill_id basis. Means array with same bill id must come under one section. Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: What You Have tried to achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean by under one section? Whats your expected output?

Comment: Please add your expected output so that community can provide better solution in quick time.

Comment: means first  arrays with same bill_id here it is first three. these should be in an array.

Answer (score 0):

That's call group by, check this [link](http://ouzo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utils/arrays.html#groupby)

```
$bill_id = Arrays::groupBy($actual_array, Functions::extractField('bill_id'));
```

Hope this helps you.